# Backbone saving model list to collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to add a list of models to a collection to be stored locally. I don't fully understand backbone yet which is really the cause of this problem.

I basically pull in an RSS feed, assign each item in the feed to a Model and try place the list of Models into a collection so I can iterate over them later.

I am getting an error saying that I need to specify a Url for the collection.

It would be brilliant if someone could explain to me the correct process I need to follow to achieve my goal.

Currently I have:

```
var DetailIndividual = Backbone.Model.extend();     
var DetailsIndividual = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: DetailIndividual
});

var Search = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click a.individualCast' : 'pullIndividual'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.detailsIndividual = new DetailsIndividual();
        _this = this;
        this.detailsIndividual.bind('reset', function(collection) {
            collection.each(function(item) {
                //code to handle update
            });
        });
    },
    pullIndividual: function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        //Logic to pull in RSS feed
        for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
            entry[i] = new DetailIndividual({ title: result.feed.entries[i].title, link: result.feed.entries[i].link, });
        }
        this.detailsIndividual.add(entry);


    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is reported out from here,because model must have url attribute:
http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-167

do you model have url attribute?

Comment: It doesnt, I dont want to use a url attribute as I wont be saving the model data anywhere. Is there anything I can do to work around the need for the url attribute?

Comment: @blacktea By default, you must specify the url property, unless you rewrite backbone.sync.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting the error is because you're binding the 'reset' event. 'reset' is only fired on a collection.fetch or an explicit call to collection.reset, and in your case you're never fetching from the server with your collection - I'm assuming from your code you already have the feed in memory - so unless you're explicitly resetting, there's no need to listen for the reset.

In your code, you're not really extending Collection and Model, so it's actually not necessary to make extended objects - just use Backbone.Collection. You don't even need to create a Model extension because by default, when you add a JSON, a Backbone.Model is automatically created. It's only necessary to assign the collection.model if you're creating a truly custom model (with method overrides and additions).

Here's a way you could load your collection:

```
var search = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click a.individualCast' : 'pullIndividual'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.detailsIndividual = new Backbone.Collection();
    },
    pullIndividual: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        //Logic to pull in RSS feed
        for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
            this.detailsIndividual.add({
                title: result.feed.entries[i].title, 
                link: result.feed.entries[i].link
            });
        }
    } 
});
```

You didn't provide any code of how you wanted to parse collection (except in the 'reset'), but essentially you'd load the collection from the feed as shown.